# Calculating Krippendorf's alpha for a single response

Tags: r, survey

I'm looking for a method to calculate Krippendorf's alpha for a single question with multiple responders.

Is this possible? The R packages 'rel' and 'irr' have functions for Krippendorf's alpha, but they all require at least two responses (i.e. questions).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only have 1 response, then you will have an `alpha = 1`, which is perfect match. Are you talking about a single response or single response variable?

Comment: @akash87 Example: 45 individuals are responding to one survey question, with each individual answering 'Yes' or 'No' for that one question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't enough reputation to comment, but if you just use the same data twice  shouldn't you get the same value as if you calculated with one question. Just make a second questions with the same responses as the first one?